# Nomination Pool Question

Tags: polkadot-js, staking

We would like to know What parameter should we pass in as “extra” for bondExtra(extra)? And what does it mean for the type “PalletNominationPoolsBondExtra”

[image: nominationPools]

Thank you, the Starfish team

Answer (score 3):

This is the definition of the type `PalletNominationPoolsBondExtra`

```
  interface PalletNominationPoolsBondExtra extends Enum {
    readonly isFreeBalance: boolean;
    readonly asFreeBalance: u128;
    readonly isRewards: boolean;
    readonly type: 'FreeBalance' | 'Rewards';
  }
```

For that call you have to select if you want to bond this additional funds  from either the free balance of the account, of from the accumulated rewards.

If you try to send the Extrinsic using PolkadotJS UI you can see that you can pick between `FreeBalance` or `Rewards` and pick the amount. See the image below.

[image]

Comment: You can also read about it in the Rust docs [here](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_nomination_pools/enum.BondExtra.html).